# make div as wide as the window(responsive)

Tags: css, width

Is there a way I can make the background of a div as wide as the browser window, independent of the width of the div? Doesn't work if I set a container for the div. The background is always as wide as the div, even if I set a container. As soon as I test it on a mobile size the div isn't as wide as the window anymore.
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you fiddle here

Answer (score -1):

Give the width of background as 100% so that it can fit to any window size .